# How to display data from a pop up view controller

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a reminders app and I have a view controller with a table view. When I press a button, a pop up view controller appears to enter the name and description. When I dismiss the pop up, the text entered in the two text fields does not display on my table view cell. The print function was just to check if the name and description of the category was appended to allCategories, which it was.

```
  @IBAction func createPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    allCategories.append(Categories(name: nameTF.text!, description: descriptionTF.text!, activities: []))
    print(allCategories)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

edit here's the code in the view controller that has the table view:
Edit #2: I printed allCategories in viewWillAppear under reloadData() and it prints the correct thing. I changed the return in numberOfRowsInSection to allCategories.count and now it displays stuff in the table view but each time I add a category/description it repeatedly displays the first category and description. Also, it displays the name of the category in one cell and the description in the other, I just want it to display the name and have the description as a subtitle

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var theTableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allCategories.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //when cell is pressed
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return allCategories.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = allCategories[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    theTableView.reloadData()
    print(allCategories)
}
```

Comment: You are not adding in the allCategories of the view controller with tableview.

Comment: Can you add the code where you present the popup view controller

Comment: @RaziTiwana I just made the segue from the view controller that contains the table view one that presents modally. If it helps i have this written in the view controller with the table view:                func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = allCategories[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
 
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        theTableView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: okay just tell me that the viewController with table view presents the viewController with `createPressed ` right? and you have` allCategories` in both of the Controlllers?

Comment: @RaziTiwana when the create button is pressed the popup should go away and present the view controller with the table view (and update the table view to display the information). All view controllers have access to allCategories because it's declared above the class and it's referenced in both view controllers

Comment: Then maybe your reloadData() is not being called or you have problem with `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Add your Code in the question to get a better answer rather than my assumptions :p

Comment: You need to use some `delegation` to pass `allCategories` array from popup to `tableView viewController`. `Array's` are `value types` not `reference types` so you need to set it again.

Comment: why in numberOfRowsInSection yout get number from "allActivities", but your cellForRowAt indexPath: you get data from "allCategories" and numberOfSection you get number from "allCategories" ?

maybe you should replace return between numberOfSection & numberOfRows

Comment: @Fadielse if I return allActivities[section].count in numberOfRowsInSections I gat an error - use of unresolved identifier section